# How to connect to a websocket that requires authentication using flutter?

Tags: flutter, websocket

I'm trying to implement a websocket connection in my flutter app. Right now it does work if the connection is a non authenticated one, but if it requires authentications I keep getting this error:

> Flutter: WebSocketException: Connection to
> 'http://myServer.org' was not
> upgraded to websocket

For the websocket I tried with Stomp_dart_client using this code:

```
 _stompClient = StompClient(
      config: StompConfig(
        url: url,
        stompConnectHeaders: {
                      'Connection': 'Upgrade',
             'Upgrade': 'websocket',
          'Authorization': token
          },
        webSocketConnectHeaders: {
            'Connection': 'Upgrade',
             'Upgrade': 'websocket',
            'Authorization': '$token',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        onConnect: (StompFrame frame) {
          emit(const WebsocketState.DataReceived('Connected'));
          debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
          debugPrint(frame.body);
           debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
          _subscribeToTopic();
        },
        onWebSocketError: (error) {
          emit(WebsocketState.Error(error.toString()));
           debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
          debugPrint(error.toString());
           debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
        },

      ),
    );

    _stompClient!.activate();
  }
```

I tried setting just the  webSocketConnectHeaders or just the stompConnectHeaders.

I tried also using the flutter web socket library (dart:io),
with this code:

```
  try {
  _socket = await WebSocket.connect(
  url, 
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token,
  }
  );
  _socket!.listen(
    (data) {
      emit(WebsocketState.DataReceived(data));
      debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
      debugPrint(data);
      debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
    },
    onError: (error) {
      emit(WebsocketState.Error(error.toString()));
      debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
      debugPrint(error.toString());
      debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
    },
    onDone: () {
      emit(const WebsocketState.Closed());
    },
  );
} catch (e) {
  emit(WebsocketState.Error(e.toString()));
  debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
  debugPrint(e.toString());
  debugPrint('----------------                -----------------');
}
```

in both cases I get the same error and this is I the server shows:

> 2023-11-21T15:38:16,234 TRACE [http-nio-8083-exec-1]
> i.a.c.JwtHandshakeInterceptor: Token url null 2023-11-21T15:38:16,234
> TRACE [http-nio-8083-exec-1] i.a.c.JwtHandshakeInterceptor: Shouldn't
> accept connections

Answer (score 0):

The main things (that I can't see)

Make sure when passing tokens, your using Bearer before the token (if applicable).
For Bearer tokens, it typically looks like `'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'.`

also make sure your not needing CORS. As I've had issues in the past needing to verify with CORS, however seeing as you can make a connection without it if your not using the token I doubt that's the case.

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't it, apparently there was something related with the loadbalancers that prevent the connection upgrade from happening.